# How are dots in the corner called and how to disable them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

My PyQt5 mainwindow (QMainWindow) has some dots in the right bottom corner. When you hoover with your mouse over it the mouse cursor changes in a resize icon. How are these dots called? How to hide or disable them, as well how to stop the mouse on changing cursor icon?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its called the sizegrip and is used for resizing the window. To disable it, try this:

```
mainwindow.statusBar().setSizeGripEnabled(False)
```

You could then make the window a fixed size with e.g

```
 mainwindow.setFixedSize(500, 500)
```

Answer (score 1):

By accident I just found it. People call it resize handle or "SizeGrip" and you can disable it using

```
self.statusBar().setSizeGripEnabled(False)
```

or

```
mainwindow.statusBar().setSizeGripEnabled(False)
```