# How can I remove the window corner resize icon?

Tags: c++, qt

I made a qt application and disabled the resize but the window show resize option.

Here is the image:

[image]

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint|Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint|Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
w.setFixedSize(QSize(1080,740));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are dots in the corner called and how to disable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166626/how-are-dots-in-the-corner-called-and-how-to-disable-them)

Comment: Another duplicate: [How can I get rid of the resize-handle in a QDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575294/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-resize-handle-in-a-qdialog)

Comment: Note that you should not call `setWindowFlags()` arbitrarily with new flags unless you *really* know what you're doing, as it completely overrides the current flags. See the difference between [`setWindowFlag()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowFlag) and the [`windowFlags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) property (notice the difference in the singular/plural forms between `setWindowFlag()` and `setWindowFlags()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is linked to the `SizeGrip` property of the [Qdialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialog.html), you can remove it with

```
dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```